# Is it possible to take a power series expansion "in the monster group"

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, simple-groups

Given the [monster group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monster_group), I have no idea what it means to take a power series expansion in this group, I just made up this expression and have been trying to give it a meaningful definition.  My main question is whether or not this is a good idea or a bad idea.  I will provide some more details.

Let's say the size of the monster group is $M$ then I am thinking about the general linear group of dimension $M$, $GL_M(\mathbb{R})$ and doing matrix power series, then investigating the lie algebra of this type of system.  But what I really want is not the entire general linear group, but just the subset corresponding to the representations of the monster group

ok so now I have all the representations of the monster group and am doing formal power series operations on them, is this useful for anything?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not try it first for some easier group like Klein-4 or $S_3$ or dihedral group. If you can't get anything out of it for those groups, not likely it will be useful for the monster.

Comment: This is a good idea, thanks Gerry!  If I make any progress I will post another questions that reveals more of the motivation.